# Remove the selection from a JList in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to remove the selection at my JList, after an item has been clicked, because it then can not be clicked again without moving the selection.

I'vet tried this, but keep getting an error, and i don't see what is going on.

```
    ListSelectionModel mode = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
    mode.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    mode.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() 
    {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) 
        {

            // Åben url'en i en browser
            if( !evt.getValueIsAdjusting() )
            {

                if(isDownloaded(data_alle.get(list_alle.getSelectedIndex()),data_downloaded))
                {
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(data_downloaded.get(list_alle.getSelectedIndex()).getPath()));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    OpenURI.open(data_alle.get(list_alle.getSelectedIndex()).getUrl(), url);
                }
                list_alle.clearSelection();

            }
        }

    });

    list_alle.setSelectionModel(mode);
```

And the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at gui.Kursus$2.valueChanged(Kursus.java:114)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeSelectionIntervalImpl(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.clearSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.clearSelection(Unknown Source)
at gui.Kursus$2.valueChanged(Kursus.java:127)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.setValueIsAdjusting(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You are not showing the relevant code. The problem lies in what your `//dostuff` but you don't show that part. As a general rule, and in particular for Swing problems, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Also, I would avoid clearing the selection within the handling of the list selection event. At least move the code into a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.

Comment: what is line 114 at `gui.Kursus$2.valueChanged(Kursus.java:114)`?

Comment: The exception message clearly states that gui.Kursus$2.valueChanged() (Kursus.java, line 114) invokes get(-1) on an ArrayList; but list indices are from 0 upwards.

Comment: Much More Code would be useful. I had similar problem, i think it can be solved by seeing more code.

Comment: I have shown all the //do stuff now! This i btw from the Kursus-class. Line 114 is the one, where i check the isDownloaded in an if-statement. Line 127 is list_alle.clearSelection();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your selection handler you are not making any out of bounds check for the selected item

```
if( !evt.getValueIsAdjusting() && list_alle.getSelectedIndex() >= 0) {...}
```

What's happening is

1. The selection changes and enters you handlers code, you process the change and clear the selection
2. Your handler is notified of the change to the selection (again), you process the change and hit an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` because nothing's selected

Answer (score 0):

Since relevant code / line #s are missing from your question, my best guess is as follows:

I had a similar problem with selection manipulation for JList. When you are determining the index of what is being selected, the reported index from `getMinSelectionIndex()` and related calls will sometimes report 0 as negative numbers (may have something to do with deltas, but I am admitted unsure). Place a manual check to ensure that the index you are working with isn't negative:

```
 89     class SharedListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {
 90         public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
 91             ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();
 92 
 93             if (!lsm.getValueIsAdjusting()){
 94                 int index = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
 95                 if (index < 0) {
 96                     index = 0;
 97                 }
 98                 handleListSelectionEvent(index);
 99             }
100 
101         }
102     }
```

Comment: list_alle.getSelectedIndex() will return -1 if nothing is selected,this is documented behaviour